# PHP Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'XML_PATH_CUSTOM_ADMIN_PATH in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php on line 342

Tags: magento, windows-shell

i upgraded the magento site from 1.4.1.1 to latest version.

But when i loading the site it displays white page .

And in fire bug it displays network server error.

So i checked the errors using ssh.

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

it displays some errors :

```
   root@MSHOME:/var/www/magento_upgrade# tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
[Tue Jul 31 12:15:20 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.11] PHP Fatal error:  Undefined class constant 'XML_PATH_CUSTOM_ADMIN_PATH' in /var/www/magento_upgrade/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php on line 342
[Tue Jul 31 12:15:20 2012] [error] [client 192.168.1.11] PHP Fatal error:  Undefined class constant 'XML_PATH_CUSTOM_ADMIN_PATH' in /var/www/magento_upgrade/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php on line 342
[Tue Jul 31 12:15:30 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Jul 31 12:15:32 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.6.12 PHP/5.3.5-1ubuntu7.10 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jul 31 12:17:18 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Jul 31 12:17:20 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.6.12 PHP/5.3.5-1ubuntu7.10 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jul 31 12:32:41 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Jul 31 12:32:42 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.6.12 PHP/5.3.5-1ubuntu7.10 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jul 31 12:49:04 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Jul 31 12:49:05 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.6.12 PHP/5.3.5-1ubuntu7.10 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
```

how can i solve this?

If there is any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Mage_Adminhtml_Helper_Data::XML_PATH_CUSTOM_ADMIN_PATH class constant has been added in Community Edition version 1.6.1.0.

If you have upgraded you Magento from 1.4.1.1 to the latest, double check that you have the following file successfully upgraded:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Data.php
```

it should have in the following lines:

```
const XML_PATH_USE_CUSTOM_ADMIN_PATH = 'default/admin/url/use_custom_path';
const XML_PATH_CUSTOM_ADMIN_PATH = 'default/admin/url/custom_path';
```

If it doesn't, your upgrade process had some failures. I would go and make sure that each file in your upgraded Magento installation folder (following subfolders) corresponds exactly to the ones in the Magento version you have upgraded to (you can use Git or Diff to check):

- app/code
- app/etc/modules
- lib

Also check that compilation is switched off, and clean the cache before retrying. If you use APC or similar PHP opcode caches, please also restart your PHP service (apache, php-fpm etc), as PHP bytecode may be stale in those caches.